# ML Build error for Catalyst (Xcode 12 GM)

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, ios14, xcode12

Anyone else having issues with the GM release with ML models and has a solution for this? I get the following error:

`Type 'MLModel' has no member '__loadContents'`

I have cleaned the Project + deleted derived data (this is a generated file that is put into the derived data folder)

I notice that the method should not be there for mac OS 10.15 which I use, but it there for some reason.

I also noticed that this API is still in beta while the GM is a production build? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel

Should I regenerate the ML model?

[image: xcode error]

Comment: same issue, but my model comes from a conversion coremltool (TF -> CoreML)

Comment: Indeed there is bug that will be fixed in Xcode 12.2, Apple provides a solution https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/930

Comment: issue persists on macOS 11 Beta (20A5395g)

Comment: posted on the Apple forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664333

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Root cause of this is :

> CoreML compiler in Xcode 12.0 GM is generating code that has symbols available only on macOS BigSur causing the compilation issue. If the goal is to build a catalyst or macOS-only app with Xcode 12.0

Steps to fix :

1. In your targets build settings you can set COREML_CODEGEN_LANGUAGE to "None"
2. Open terminal then go to where your .mlmodel folder
3. Type "xcrun coremlcompiler generate <YourModel.mlmodel> --language Swift ."
4. This will create <YourModel.swift> file in same folder.
5. Open Xcode and add <YourModel.swift> in your project.
6. Click <YourModel.swift> and comment out method that compiler complains.

In my case I comment out :

```
class func load(contentsOf modelURL: URL, configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration(), completionHandler handler: @escaping (Swift.Result<Nudity, Error>) -> Void)
```

and

```
class func load(configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration(), completionHandler handler: @escaping (Swift.Result<Nudity, Error>) -> Void)
```

methods to fix swift file.

Comment: got this error on step 3:
"coremlcompiler: error: generate command missing destination path"

Anyone had same issue?

Comment: I did not need to go beyond step 1, Xcode build worked after setting to "None". Xcode 12.1 on Catalina.