# How to add a CoreML model into a Swift package?

Tags: swift, coreml, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to write a Swift package that uses a CoreML model.
I'm not very familiar with Swift packages creation and I could not make it work.
Here is what I've done based on the different posts I've read so far:

1. Create an empty package

```
$ mkdir MyPackage
$ cd MyPackage
$ swift package init
$ swift build
$ swift test
```

2. Open the `Package.swift` file with XCode
3. Drag and drop the `MyModel.mlmodel` file into the folder `Sources/MyPackage`

When I click on the `MyModel.mlmodel` file in XCode, I have the following message displayed under the class name:

```
Model is not part of any target. Add the model to a target to enable generation of the model class.
```

Similarly, if I use the command `swift build` in a Terminal I get the following message:

```
warning: found 1 file(s) which are unhandled; explicitly declare them as resources or exclude from the target
    /Path/To/MyPackage/Sources/MyPackage/MyModel.mlmodel
```

4. To solve this, I added `MyModel` into the target resources in the file `Package.swift`:

```
.target(
    name: "MyPackage",
    dependencies: [],
    resources: [.process("MyModel.mlmodel")]),
```

If I now use the command `$ swift build`, I don't have the warning anymore and I get the message:

```
[3/3] Merging module MyPackage
```

But when I check the `MyModel.mlmodel` file in XCode, I have the following message displayed under the class name:

```
Model class has not been generated yet.
```

5. To solve this, I used the following command in a Terminal:

```
$ cd Sources/MyPackage 
$ xcrun coremlcompiler generate MyModel.mlmodel --language Swift .
```

This generated a `MyModel.swift` file next to the mlmodel file.

6. I plugged the model in the code `MyPackage.swift`:

```
import CoreML

@available(iOS 12.0, *)
struct MyPackage {
    var model = try! MyModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
}
```

7. Finally, in the test file `MyPackageTests.swift`, I create an instance of MyPackage:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyPackage

final class MyPackageTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            let foo = MyPackage()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    static var allTests = [
        ("testExample", testExample),
    ]
}
```

I get the following error (it seems that the CoreML model was not found):

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I must have missed something...
I hope my description was clear and detailed enough.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is probably where it goes wrong: `var model = try! MyModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())`

Since you've added a mlmodel file to the package, it hasn't been compiled yet. I'm not an expert on Swift packages, but I don't believe Xcode automatically compiles this model now. You can see this for yourself when you open up the compiled app bundle -- does it have the mlmodel file in it or the mlmodelc folder?

You may need to add the mlmodelc to the package, not the mlmodel. You can create this by doing:

```
$ xcrun coremlcompiler compile MyModel.mlmodel .
```

Next, in your app you will need to load the model as follows:

```
let url = YourBundle.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "mlmodelc")!
let model = try! MyModel(contentsOf: url, configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
```

where `YourBundle` is a reference to the bundle that contains the mlmodelc file (which I guess is the bundle for the Swift package).

Answer (score 8):

The solution described bellow worked for me. I hope it is correct.

**Conversion of the MLModel**

The MLModel cannot be used directly in the Swift package. It first needs to be converted.

```
$ cd /path/to/folder/containg/mlmodel
$ xcrun coremlcompiler compile MyModel.mlmodel .
$ xcrun coremlcompiler generate MyModel.mlmodel . --language Swift
```

The first `xcrun` command will compile the model and create a folder named `MyModel.mlmodelc`.
The second `xcrun` command will generate a `MyModel.swift` file.

**Add the model to the Swift package**

We consider that a Swift package already exists and is located in `/path/to/MyPackage/`.

1. Copy the `MyModel.mlmodelc` folder and `MyModel.swift` file into the folder `/path/to/MyPackage/Sources/MyPackage`
2. Add the `MyModel.mlmodelc` in the target resources in the file `Package.swift`:

```
.target(
    name: "MyPackage",
    dependencies: [],
        resources: [.process("MyModel.mlmodelc")]),
```

**Instantiate MyModel**

In the Swift code, simply create an instance of MyModel:

```swift
let model = try? MyModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
```

or:

```swift
let url = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "mlmodelc")!
let model = try? MyModel(contentsOf: url, configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
```

**Troubleshooting**

I got a `Type 'MLModel' has no member '__loadContents'` error at first.
This seems to be a bug related to XCode 12.
I simply commented the 2 functions that caused a problem.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917164/ml-build-error-for-catalyst-xcode-12-gm) and [here](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/930) for more information.

Comment: Looks good, but you will have issues with `resources: [.process(...)]` if you have more than one model in your target. Better to use `.copy(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of precompile your model you can compile on the fly:

```
if let url = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "mlmodel") {
    let compiledURL = try! MLModel.compileModel(at: url)
    let model = try! MLModel(contentsOf: compiledURL, configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
} else if let url = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "mlmodelc") {
    let model = try! MLModel(contentsOf: url, configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
}
```

You still need to add resources to your target:

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyPackage",
        dependencies: [],
        resources: [.process("MyMLFolder")]]
    ),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyPackage Tests",
        dependencies: ["MyPackage"]
    ),
]
```